# Como pegar um output parameter do MySql via C#

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

Pesquisei e apliquei o que vi, porém está dando erro:

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(banco.Conexao);
MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("sp_venda", con);
comando.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

comando.Parameters.Add("usuario", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = banco.Usuario;
comando.Parameters.Add("dinheiro", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = banco.formataDinheiro(Venda.Dinheiro);
comando.Parameters.Add("debito", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = banco.formataDinheiro(Venda.Dinheiro);
comando.Parameters.Add("credito", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = banco.formataDinheiro(Venda.Dinheiro);
comando.Parameters.Add("voucher", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = banco.formataDinheiro(Venda.Dinheiro);
comando.Parameters.Add("desconto", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = banco.formataDinheiro(VendaBLL.somaDescontos().ToString());
comando.Parameters.Add("troco", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = banco.formataDinheiro(Venda.Troco);

MySqlParameter paramHorario = new MySqlParameter("horario", MySqlDbType.Time);
paramHorario.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

comando.Parameters.Add(paramHorario);

con.Open();
comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
Venda.Horario = comando.Parameters["horario"].Value.ToString();
con.Close();
```

O erro ocorre na seguinte linha:

```
comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

A conexão abre normalmente. O erro retornado é: "FormatException: Cadeia de entrada não estava em um formato incorreto."
O que estou fazendo de errado?

**Edit**

```
 public static string formataDinheiro(string grana)
 {
   if (DetectaTipo(grana) == "null")
      return "null";

 return grana.Replace("R$ ", "").Replace(",", ".");
 }
```

Comment: Poderia por favor colocar aqui sua função `banco.formataDinheiro()`?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez pronto (:

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quer dizer que algum dos seus parâmetros não está formatado como se deve. Sua função `banco.formataDinheiro()` não está devolvendo um `Double`, e sim um `String`. Por isso o erro.

Para se trabalhar com dinheiro, o ideal é o tipo `Decimal`. O `Double` pode trazer complicadores, como problemas nos arredondamentos.

Comment: Funcionou! Não imaginava que poderia ser isso por que enquanto debugava o compilador passava por essa parte tranquilamente. Seguirei seu conselho e mudarei o tipo pra decimal. Assim que der, marco a resposta como correta

Comment: É porque os parâmetros são resolvidos em tempo de execução do comando. Por isso o erro é "tardio".